# Ejecutar un archivo .jar desde un script en batch

Tags: cmd, batch, jar

Resulta que en el CMD si me permite ejecutar el siguiente comando:

```
C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Codigo\LibGDX\libgdx-nightly-latest\java -cp gdx.jar;gdx-natives.jar;gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar;gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar;extensions\gdx-tools\gdx-tools.jar com.badlogic.gdx.tools.particleeditor.ParticleEditor
```

Pero el quisiera saber como ejecutar este mismo comando pero con un archivo .bat

He intentado con esto:

```
@echo off

C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Codigo\LibGDX\libgdx-nightly-latest\java -cp gdx.jar;gdx-natives.jar;gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar;gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar;extensions\gdx-tools\gdx-tools.jar com.badlogic.gdx.tools.particleeditor.ParticleEditor 
pause
exit
```

Pero me sale el siguiente problema:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo el link, donde se encuentra el archivo, con el que tengo el problema: [Aqui](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Particle-Editor)

Comment: Tienes un link, de donde se pueda realizar la descarga del archivo que intentas ejecutar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He descargado el programa que tu estas planteando `ParticleEditor`, he realizado las pruebas. Tambien se presento el problema.

En ese caso podrias intentarlo asi:

```
@echo off

cd C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Codigo\LibGDX\libgdx-nightly-latest\

java -cp gdx.jar;gdx-natives.jar;gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar;gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar;extensions\gdx-tools\gdx-tools.jar com.badlogic.gdx.tools.particleeditor.ParticleEditor

pause
exit
```

Lo que se ha hecho aqui, no es gran cambio, respecto a lo que ya tenias.

En lugar de ejecutar toda la ruta absoluta para poder abrir el programa, lo que se hace es usar el comando `cd`, para dirigirnos a la carpeta que contiene nuestro programa.

> cd C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Codigo\LibGDX\libgdx-nightly-latest\

Estando alli, ejecutamos el archivo tal como lo has hecho tu.

> java -cp gdx.jar;gdx-natives.jar;gdx-backend-lwjgl.jar;gdx-backend-lwjgl-natives.jar;extensions\gdx-tools\gdx-tools.jar com.badlogic.gdx.tools.particleeditor.ParticleEditor

Al realizar las pruebas de esta manera se ejecuta correctamente.

Comment: Gracias amigo me ha funcionado, habia intentado con cd pero al parecer mi problema era que lo ejecutaba todo en una sola linea, me fuiste de gran ayuda!!, ya estaba arto de entrar a cmd y ejecutar ese comando. Saludos!